# Axum pgconnection through shared state

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, rust-axum

I want to share the PgConnection through the app level state to all the routes and services
trying to achieve dependency injection.

The problem I am facing is, `sqlx` requires `mut reference` to the connection.
While axum uses `Arc` to provide `immutable reference` of the state across all the processes that it spins.

This forces me to use `Arc<Mutex<PgConnection>>` just so that I have mutable reference to satisfy `sqlx`

```rust
pub struct AppState {
    pub db_connection: Arc<Mutex<PgConnection>>,
    pub jwt: JWTSettings,
}
```

And this is how I use it in the route

```rust
pub async fn sign_up(
        State(state): State<Arc<AppState>>,
        Json(signup_payload): Json<SignupPayload>,
    ) -> Result<Json<LoginResponse>, StatusCode> {
 let mut connection = state.db_connection.lock().unwrap();
    sqlx::query!("select * from users where username=$1", signup_payload.username)
        .fetch_one(&mut*connection)
        .await
        .map_err(|err| {
            println!("ERROR: Unable to execute the query {:?}", err);
            return StatusCode::INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
        });
```

**Issue** I don't want the route/thread to hold the connection `lock` otherwise there is no point of worker processes to run parallely.

Answer (score 3):

You should not use a single connection, but a [connection pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool). This will allow  an efficient reuse of connections.

[`sqlx` provides support for pools](https://docs.rs/sqlx/latest/sqlx/type.PgPool.html):

```rust
pub struct AppState {
    pub db_pool: sqlx::PgPool,
    pub jwt: JWTSettings,
}

pub async fn sign_up(
    State(state): State<Arc<AppState>>,
    Json(signup_payload): Json<SignupPayload>,
) -> Result<Json<LoginResponse>, StatusCode> {
    let mut connection = state.db_pool.acquire().await.unwrap();
    sqlx::query!(
        "select * from users where username=$1",
        signup_payload.username
    )
    .fetch_one(&mut *connection)
    .await
    .map_err(|err| {
        println!("ERROR: Unable to execute the query {:?}", err);
        return StatusCode::INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, whether in Rust or in another programming language, you should never keep a long-lived connection. This can break your application if, for instance, there is maintenance on the database.

Rather, you should keep a connection *pool*. This will reuse a connection if one is available, otherwise it will connect you.

If I understand correctly, you are using sqlx. It [supports pools out of the box](https://docs.rs/sqlx/latest/sqlx/pool/index.html).

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean when you say "This will reuse a connection if one is available, otherwise it will connect you." ?

Comment: The general idea of a database connection pool is that you ask it to give you a connection. If this is the first time you connect to the database, the pool will create a connection and return it. Once you stop using this connection (i.e. at the end of your request), the pool will keep the connection alive for a while, in case you need it again. If the connection is broken (for instance because the database server was restarted) or if all connections are currently busy, next time you ask the pool for a connection, it will reconnect you.

Comment: If you're in a hurry, use @Chayim Friedman's solution :) It uses a database connection pool.